# if f(x) is not derivable at x=a then can |f(x)| be derivable at x=a

Tags: calculus, limits

I was thinking that if
$$ f(x) = 1, \, x \leq 5 \, \text{and} \,  -1 \, \text{for} \,  x > 5$$
and, here, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=5$ but $|f(x)|= 1$, $x \in \mathcal{R}$ is differentiable at $x=a$.

Comment: your example does it

Comment: "differentiable" is the term in English.

Comment: Now, look for a continuous example.